# React-Native: Getting exception: invokeGuardedCallbackAndCatchFirstError

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios

1. In my application there is common action defined to call a specific API.
2. This action/API can get called from different tabs / internal screens of tabs.
3. I am getting the exception, when I called action from one tab and tried accessing same action from another tab for same API.
4. As per the input params, this same API response with two different outputs.
5. There is an exception occurring while making second call from another tab. In error, it seems that the second call trying to access the output parameters which are actually expected for first call.

**Question: Is there any issue while using same same Actions across multiple places simultaneously? Do I need to create/duplicate Actions for each tabs/calls?**

React Info:
    "axios": "^0.16.2",
    "react": "16.0.0-alpha.12",
    "react-native": "0.47.1",

[PFA image to see the exception messages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bm3GB.png)

Comment: code excerpt would be preferred

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Eduard , but we just got the solution. The issue was arising due to wrong references used at UI components.
e.g.

```
render()
{
  onTapped = this.props.onTapped
  return (
  <View>
    <GridView
     ...         
     renderItem={this.renderItem}        
     .../>
  </View>
  );
 }
```

AND 
the 'this.renderItem' functions was:

```
renderItem(item)
{         
 onPress={() => onTapped(item)}
}
```

We just replaced, onTapped(item) with "this.props.onTapped(item)" AND used ES6 syntax to define method "renderItem = (item) => {}"

Closing the thread, as this issue is resolved now.